# Contact form keeps redirecting to php page

Tags: php, html, forms

I've been stuck on an issue for my contact form for the past few days for some reason when submitting the contact form it redirects to the php page that the form uses to process the request. I am using the same code I have on another website of mine and that works with no problems may someone help to see what is happening

This is whats on index.php

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=test"></script>
        <script>
            function onClick(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                grecaptcha.ready(function() {
                    grecaptcha.execute('test', {action: 'contact'}).then(function(token) {
                        var recaptchaResponse = document.getElementById('recaptchaResponse');
                        recaptchaResponse.value = token;
                    });
                });
            }
        </script>

<?php
                        // Check if form was submitted:
                        if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST' && isset($_POST['recaptcha_response'])) {
                            // Build POST request:
                            $recaptcha_url = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify';
                            $recaptcha_secret = 'test';
                            $recaptcha_response = $_POST['recaptcha_response'];

                            // Make and decode POST request:
                            $recaptcha = file_get_contents($recaptcha_url . '?secret=' . $recaptcha_secret . '&response=' . $recaptcha_response);
                            $recaptcha = json_decode($recaptcha);

                            // Take action based on the score returned:
                            if ($recaptcha->score >= 0.5) {
                                // Verified - send email
                            }
                            else {
                                // Not verified - show form error
                            }
                        }
                    ?>
                    <form method="POST" action="form.php" target="_blank">
                        <p><input class="w3-input w3-padding-16 w3-border" type="text" placeholder="Name" required name="Name"></p>
                        <p><input class="w3-input w3-padding-16 w3-border" type="text" placeholder="Subject" required name="Subject"></p>
                        <p><input class="w3-input w3-padding-16 w3-border" type="email" placeholder="Email" required name="Email"></p>
                        <p><input class="w3-input w3-padding-16 w3-border" type="text" placeholder="Message" required name="Message"></p>
                        <p><button class="w3-button w3-black" type="submit">SEND MESSAGE</button></p>
                        <p><input type="hidden" name="recaptcha_response" id="recaptchaResponse"></p>
                    </form>
```

This is whats on form.php

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  $name = $_POST['Name'];
  $visitor_email = $_POST['Email'];
  $email_subject = $_POST['Subject'];
  $message = $_POST['Message'];

  $email_from = $visitor_email;
  $email_subject = $email_subject;
  $email_body = "Name: $name \n".
                "Email: $visitor_email \n".
                "Message: $message \n";



  $to = "test@gmail.com";
  $headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";
  $headers = "Reply-To: $visitor_email \r\n";
  mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
  header("Location: index.php");
}
?>
```

Comment: You need to post all relevant code into the question itself and not as a link off-site.

Comment: post you code here.

Comment: i think you need header("Location: index.php") in your form.php if its successfully sent

Comment: Check the html form tag. Probably you have action="form.php"

Comment: @MagnusEriksson okay sorry I was on reddit before this looking for help and they mentioned the link i used but i updated it

Comment: @PranavMS updated post

Comment: @Jerson already have that in form.php

Comment: @dragos.nicolae i do have it as action="form.php

Comment: added answer please look at

Comment: @kel as far as I understand, you want don't want to be redirected to form.php after submit right? If this is so, you need to remove the replace action="form.php" with action=" ".

Comment: no please look at my answer, if true not execute in form.php because submit post is NULL and return to false

Comment: @Jerson thank you yes that worked, I over looked that piece so many times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<form method="POST" action="form.php" target="_blank">
    <p><input class="w3-input w3-padding-16 w3-border" type="text" placeholder="Name" required name="Name"></p>
    <p><input class="w3-input w3-padding-16 w3-border" type="text" placeholder="Subject" required name="Subject"></p>
    <p><input class="w3-input w3-padding-16 w3-border" type="email" placeholder="Email" required name="Email"></p>
    <p><input class="w3-input w3-padding-16 w3-border" type="text" placeholder="Message" required name="Message"></p>
    <p><button class="w3-button w3-black" name="submit" type="submit">SEND MESSAGE</button></p>
    <p><input type="hidden" name="recaptcha_response" id="recaptchaResponse"></p>
</form>
```

Add name tag in your button, $_POST['submit'] is null because you didn't add name="submit"